# Can we implement different login url for sessiontime out and accesscontrol in Yii?

Tags: yii

Is it possible to impliment 2 login url in Yii.

that is if a sessiontimeout occurs  user should be redirected to site/login.

but when an unauthenticated user tries to access the url he should be redirected to site/loginaccount

Is it possible?

this is the code in the config file for session timeout and initializing login url

```
'components'=>array(
    'user' => array(
        'class' => 'WebUser',
        'loginUrl' => array('site/loginaccount'),
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    ),
        'session' => array(
       'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',
        'timeout'=>$params['session_timeout'],
        'autoStart'=>true,
    ),
```

This is code in my controller, which redirects to site/loginaccount if user is Guest

```
  return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('Createdeal'),
            'users'=>array('*')
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way to do this would be to put something like this in your view (or your template):

```
<head>  
        <?php if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {?>
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['session_timeout'];?>;url=http://example.com"/>
        <?php }?>
</head>
```

Obviously the URL could be generated using `createUrl()`.  You could do something similar via javascript.

Obviously all the usual disclaimers about using meta refersh and javascript redirects would apply . . . .